# Populate a ComboBox from ListBox with LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox, listbox

I can't find the answer to my question on the web..

I have a ListBox that is populated with an SQL table using LINQ (stored procedure)

I have a ComboBox that is also populated with an SQL statement using LINQ (stored procedure)
The problem is that the stored procedure for the ComboBox needs an input from the ListBox and I can't seem to cast it correctly.

Here is how my ListBox is populated :

```
private void NouvelleReservation2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExamenSGBDEntities oExamenSgbdEntities = new ExamenSGBDEntities();
        listBoxRestaurant.DataSource = oExamenSgbdEntities.SelectAllRestaurants();
        listBoxRestaurant.DisplayMember = "RESTO";
        listBoxRestaurant.ValueMember = "idRestaurants";
        listBoxRestaurant.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

And here is how my ComboBox is populated :

```
private void listBoxRestaurant_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExamenSGBDEntities oExamenSgbdEntities = new ExamenSGBDEntities();
        comboBoxTables.DataSource =
            oExamenSgbdEntities.SelectTablesByRestaurant(listBoxRestaurant.Items.Cast<Restaurant>()); //Here is where i'm struggling... I need to give the "idRestaurant" from the ListBox as parameter for my stored procedure.
        comboBoxTables.DisplayMember = "TABLECHAISE";
        comboBoxTables.ValueMember = "idTables";
    }
```

I have tried to convert the selectedItem in a DataRowView and then in an integer but that didn't work.
Have tried what you see in the code now but can't make it work.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing:

listBoxRestaurant.Items.Cast()...

Have you tried?

listBoxRestaurant.SelectedItem

Comment: I did try it. But my Item is an object and I only need its ID (i need an int)

Comment: Oh - right - my bad. You need to cast that to your class and take the ID from that...  var selectedItem = (Restaurant)listBox.SelectedItem. Then use selectedItem.Id;

Comment: I thought that would work but I still got an error when calling the cast :
System.InvalidCastException: 'Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'Reservation.SelectAllRestaurants_Result' en type 'Reservation.Restaurant'.'

Comment: I found my error. I changed the cast to SelectAllRestaurants_Result and it worked. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to pass a list of Restaurants in to your query but you say you need the id value instead? If you need one id value (as in the query accepts one input) you should use something like:

```
comboBoxTables.DataSource = oExamenSgbdEntities.SelectTablesByRestaurant(listBoxRestaurant.Items.Cast<Restaurant>().First().idRestaurant);
```

You are probably getting a cast error because it can't cast IEnumerable to int.

You could also use SelectedItem casting as Restaurant and then get the id as Jon Vote said.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but got following error :
System.InvalidCastException: 'Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'Reservation.SelectAllRestaurants_Result' en type 'Reservation.Restaurant'.'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to cast the selected list-item. Instead, use the selected value:

```
listBoxRestaurant.SelectedValue
```

Then you can load the restaurant from the database by this ID value and pass it to your `SelectTablesByRestaurant()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still doesn't work as i get an object and need only an element from that object in int

Comment: You need to cast the `SelectedValue` to `int`, then use it to get the restaurant object from the database.